# Bulk upload RAW pictures with Picasa

Tags: images, picasa, pictures

Is there a way to bulk upload RAW images to Picasa web using the Picasa software(or any other software).

I can upload RAW files using the Picasa web app but I have several thousand pictures to upload and doing it this way would take forever.

When I use the Picasa software the images are getting converted into JPEGs and I really want/need to keep them as RAWs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

#### Bulk upload

Some alternatives are discussed [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/34Hhh77VFec).

#### Keep raw format

This part of the question is not really on-topic here, but:

No, I don't believe you can. Picasa is not a generic storage system - it [supports reading of many raw formats](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=15625), but it will to convert them to JPG before storage.

If you want to store your raw files online, I'd suggest a generic storage service (since the launch of Google Drive, perhaps it is easily done within the Google framework if you want to stay there).

Comment: The RAW format is kept when uploading through the [webapp](http://picasaweb.google.com), it is only converted to JPEG when using the Picasa software

Comment: @Greg: OK, I can't find any source for this, though. You really mean that you can retrieve the images in raw format after uploading them? http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9645/is-there-any-flickr-picasa-web-service-to-store-and-share-raw-files has some suggestions, but the question is more and more coming out of scope for SU.

Comment: I am sure, I tried it with several different pictures and therefore there should be a way to do it in bulk. Generic storage is my alternative however the nice thing about picasaweb is that you can get fast previous without downloading the whole picture.